# Calling Javascript function inside controller action -YII

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, yii

I'm trying to call Javascript function inside controller action method, Is there any right way to call `setTimeout()` to be invoked on certain condition inside controller action method ?

```
window.setTimeout(function() {  
    alert("test");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:    "'.$this->createUrl("/operator/createViopNode/").'",
        data: {
            id: '.$bc_id.',
            callid:"'.$num.'",
            taskid:'.$this->taskid.'
        },
        success: function(msg){
            var ifrm = document.getElementById("frame");
            ifrm = (ifrm.contentWindow) ? ifrm.contentWindow : (ifrm.contentDocument.document) ? ifrm.contentDocument.document : ifrm.contentDocument;
            ifrm.document.open();
            ifrm.document.write(msg);
            ifrm.document.close();
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert("" + textStatus + ", " + errorThrown);
        }
    });     
}, parseInt('.$tps_call.'));
```

I need to write above js function inside controller action method, how to write this ?

Answer (score 1):

Index.csHtml

```
function abc()
 {
   alert("called")
 }
```

now Ajax Call function

```
function ExecuteAjax(URL,Data,Success)
{
    try {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: URL,
            data: Data,
            contentType: "json",
            success: function (data) { if (typeof Success == "function") { Success(data); } }
        })
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message)
    }
}
```

Call ajax like this

```
 ExecuteAjax("/Home/FillColorDropDown", "", function (data) {
            eval(data.script);
        });
```

return from controller

```
      if(demo=="true")//put condition here whatever you want
       {
         string strscript="abc();";
       }
      protected JObject jobj = new JObject();
      jobj.Add("Script", strscript);
      return Json(jobj);
```

Execute js function when controller return success

Answer (score 0):

You should register your javascript function like this:

```
function actionTest(){
  $cs = Yii::app()->clientScript;
  $cs->registerScript('my_script', 'alert("Hi there!");', CClientScript::POS_READY);
  $this->render('any_view');
}
```

[source](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/11171-call-a-javascript-function-from-a-controller/)